# How can I position an iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe, position

I need some help with positioning an iFrame. What I want is to give my iframe a slight nudge to the left. My code right now is as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://kempenvt.roccloud.nl/redrumtest/story_html5.html" scrolling="no" width="960" height="420" align="left" frameborder="0";>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
style="margin-left: -25px;"
```

as an attribute on the `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your  tag

`style="margin-right: 10px;"`

You can edit the margin as you see fit.